# An Assembler for STM32 and compatible with Ubuntu

Tags: stm32, arm, assembly, assembler

I'm new to STM32. I want to learn the architecture of STM32 using assembly language. but Keil microVision MDK-ARM is not Linux compatible. What is the alternative of Keil to write an assembly code for STM32.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gcc cross-compiler for Ubuntu.  There's a package -- gcc-arm-none-eabi -- but the last time I checked (*years ago*) the recommendation was to build the whole thing from source.

Telling you *how* to use that (and whether you need to build it) way exceeds a single post here -- I suggest a web search on "cross development for Arm Cortex M cores on Ubuntu", and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [STM32CubeIDE](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html#overview&secondary=st-get-software), download "STM32CubeIDE Debian Linux Installer". It will install Eclipse based IDE, including C/C++, and of course assembly language, along with all the fancy tool suit.

Comment: Using asm{} block in a C file?

Comment: @KiroloesAmir No, it includes an assembler to complile assembly language source files. That is the de facto developement suite from the chip manufacturer.

Comment: @KiroloesAmir , You can do either way of inline asm block or pure assembly. C startup codes are usually in assembly language that you can compile and link along with C codes.